# What is "Into the zone" in the 2017 survey?

Tags: discussion, survey

I'm filling the 2017 survey and then i see this question:

> I often get “into the zone” when I’m coding

What is "into the zone" ? Is that a reference to something ?

Comment: [How do you get into the zone? How long does it take? What steps do you take before?](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/20542)

Comment: I think that just means you often get your `momentum` going when you code. A state where you finish a lot of work and things go smoothly.

Comment: Whenever I click on Hot Meta Posts like this one, I get "out of the zone." Why do I do that?!

Comment: @magus your avatar shows that you are in the zone of battle mode!

Comment: @uom-pgregorio: It's more than that. It's more of a mental state. Achieving maximum momentum and productivity is a consequence of that.

Comment: the prison. Definitely.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is a colloquial term for a state of complete mental focus and immersion, often characterized by heightened productivity.

Another common name for the phenomenon is "flow", which was originally introduced to the field of psychology by Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi.

See also [the Wikipedia article on "flow"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)).

Comment: btw, Csikszentmihalyi is pronounced "chick sent me high" or something like this.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Mihály Csíkszentmihályi.